# Trying to escape quotes in a href tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following line of code,

```
$("#busdata").append("<div><a href="url">" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

I essentially want the "data.response.results[i].webUrl" to replace the url string, but I'm not quite sure how to escape the quotes properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape quotes by replacing them with `\"`
or just use single quotes - `'`

So `"<div><a href="url">"` becomes
`"<div><a href=\"url\">"` or `"<div><a href='url'>"`

Comment: Thank you for this. And to everybody else that answered, multiple options is always useful. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

a single quote `'` and a string concatenator `+`

```
$("#busdata").append("<div><a href='"+ data.response.results[i].webUrl +"'>" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in variable instead :

```
var url = data.response.results[i].webUrl;
$("#busdata").append("<div><a href='"+url+'">" + url + "</a></div>");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to escape quotes. Change your `<a href="url">` to `<a href=\"url\">` like this:

```
$("#busdata").append("<div><a href=\"url\">" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

Or if you feel that's a bit tough, you can exchange the quotes, `'` for `"`:

```
$("#busdata").append('<div><a href="url">' + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

Else, if you are trying to add the URL from the response:

```
$("#busdata").append("<div><a href=\"" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "\">" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

if url is a variable
`$("#busdata").append("<div><a href='" + url +"'>" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");`

and if you want to write by yourself

`$("#busdata").append("<div><a href='url'>" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");`

Answer (score 2):

Simply do it following my example:

```js
var a = $('<a />', {
href: 'url here',
text: 'text here'
}); $('body').append(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this :

```
 $("#busdata").append("<div><a href='"+data.response.results[i].webUrl +"'>" + data.response.results[i].webUrl + "</a></div>");
```

Since you are using double quotes for the string to append, you can use single quotes around the variable in the href attribute and then add that variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily achieved by not building HTML by smashing strings together in the first place.

```
$("#busdata").append(
    $("<div />").append(
        $("<a />").attr("href", data.response.results[i].webUrl)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Escaping quotes is not necessary

```
$("#busdata")
.append("<div><a href=" 
  + data.response.results[i].webUrl 
  + ">" 
  + data.response.results[i].webUrl 
  + "</a></div>"
);
```